# Play multiple different notification sounds from app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

Is it possible for an iOS or android app to launch a system notification. And have the sound played by the notification change depending on some criteria?

If so can both platforms do so?

Comment: In iOS its possible. You have to set sound file name at the time of creating notification. If it is push notification then just mention sound name in the push payload. Only one limitation is that sound file should not be of more then 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both platforms can do so.

In iOS, as mentioned in the comment, you can send a [push notification payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) with a sound filename.
For example, the following payload would display an alert and play sound-file-name if this file is bundled with your application.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"my message","sound":"sound-file-name"}}
```

In Android, when you build a notification, you can set a sound to the notification using [setSound(uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSound%28android.net.Uri,%20int%29).

> public NotificationCompat.Builder **setSound** (Uri sound)
>
> Set the sound to play. It will play on the default stream.

Or you can use [setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDefaults%28int%29) for playing the default sound.

For example :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
  .setTicker (text)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
  .setContentText (text)
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
  .setAutoCancel(true).setNumber (4)
  .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: cool! now I just need to find a cordova plugin that can do this or add this functionality to the notification cordova plugin.