# how to custom multi different sound of push notification in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to set sound when push notification, but problem is app when update or install then sound is work ok and when i push local notification and change file of sound but sound notification not change follow. it still takes the old sound.

[image]

```
var platformChannelSpecificsAndroid = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
"fcm_default_channel",
"fcm_default_channel",
channelDescription: 'Channel to Received Push Notification',
playSound: true,
styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
importance: Importance.max,
priority: Priority.high,
icon: 'launch_background',
sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(pushSound ?? ""),
);
var platformChannelSpecificsIos = new IOSNotificationDetails(
  // presentSound: true
  sound: pushSound ?? "");
var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
  android: platformChannelSpecificsAndroid,
  iOS: platformChannelSpecificsIos);

new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    hashCode,
    pushTitle,
    pushText,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: payloadT,
 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem. I found this answer [Play multiple different notification sounds from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486671/play-multiple-different-notification-sounds-from-app) . But it is only helpful for Kotlin

Comment: sr but i think it not work. my mind is setting dynamic sound instead of change 1 sound since update/install app. i think resolve only setting sound one times

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).